# Python fuzzy element checking

Tags: python, python-2.7, set, fuzzy-search

I have a Python 2.7 set object that includes the names of data categories, and I would like to be able to do some form of fuzzy element checking to see if part of a user given input is an element of the set.

Here is a toy example, to explain what I would like. Given the following set and user input:

```
SET = {'red_ball', 'green_ball', 'red_cup', 'green_cup'}
user_input = 'yellow ball'
```

I would like the program to print out something like the following:

```
'yellow_ball' not found, did you mean 'red_ball', or 'green_ball'?
```

So far I have the following:

```
import re

SET = {'red_ball', 'green_ball', 'red_cup', 'green_cup'}
user_input = 'yellow ball'

# all members of my set are lowercase and separated by an underscore
user_input_list = user_input.lower().split() # for use in fuzzy search
user_input = "_".join(user_input_list) # convert to yellow_ball for element check
regex = None
matches = []

if user_input not in SET:
    # FUZZY ELEMENT CHECK
    for item in user_input_list:
        regex = re.compile(item)
        for element in SET:
            if regex.match(element):
                matches.append(element)

    if len(matches) > 0:
        print '\'%s\' not found, did you mean %s' % (user_input, ", ".join(['\'' + x + '\'' for x in matches]))
    else:
        print '\'%s\' not found.' % user_input
```

Is there a more efficient way of doing this, perhaps that uses third party libraries?

Thanks for your help,
Geraint

Comment: Why are you using a regex? Just use `item in element`, it would do the same thing.

Comment: Does your solution work?

Comment: @Artyer thanks for your recommendation, I have changed it and it still works as expected.

Comment: @GeraintBallinger Are you interested in 3rd party libraries?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ yes, I will edit my question for clarification

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're interested in 3rd party modules, there's a nice little module I like to use for this sort of thing called [`fuzzywuzzy`](https://github.com/seatgeek/fuzzywuzzy), for fuzzy string matching in Python.

This module performs fuzzy string matching with just a couple of lines of code.

Here's an example of how you can use it:

```
>>> from fuzzywuzzy import process
>>> choices = {'red_ball', 'green_ball', 'red_cup', 'green_cup'}
>>> query = 'yellow ball'
```

We've set up our choices and input, now we can retrieve the closest matches.

```
>>> process.extract(query, choices)
[('red_ball', 53), ('green_ball', 48), ('red_cup', 13), ('green_cup', 10)]
```

This returns all choices in descending order of closeness of match. The distance between strings is computed using the Levenshtein Distance metric. You can extract the top `n` items and propose them as valid alternatives *if* the original input isn't present in the choices set.

If you want only the top match, just do this:

```
>>> process.extractOne(query, choices)
('red_ball', 53)
```

You can peruse more examples using fuzzy string matching [here](https://marcobonzanini.com/2015/02/25/fuzzy-string-matching-in-python/).

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite of your program.  Removed regular expressions.  Did not know if you wanted underscore or space as word seperator (this can be easily changed).

```
SET = ( 'red ball', 'green ball', 'red cup', 'green cup')

# For each element in the set, build a list of words
WORDS = {}
for s in SET:
  WORDS[s] = list( s.split(' ') )

# get user input
user_input = 'yellow ball'

if user_input not in SET:
  # determine possible answers
  input_words = user_input.split(' ')
  other_answers = []
  for s in WORDS:
    if any(w in WORDS[s] for w in input_words):
      other_answers.append(s)
  # print result
  if len(other_answers) > 0:
    print "'%s' not found, did you mean %s" % (
      user_input, 
      ", or ".join(["'%s'" % oa for oa in other_answers])
    )
  else:
    print "'%s' not found" % user_input
```